# How to zip and rename a directory tree

Tags: zip

I have a lot of music in a lot of directories:

```
./artist1/album1/*.mp3
./artist1/album2/*.mp3
./artist1/album3/*.mp3
./artist2/album1/*.mp3
./artist2/album2/*.mp3
./artist3/album1/*.mp3
./artist3/album2/*.mp3
... ...
```

How can I zip them to this:

```
./artist1/album1/*.mp3  => ./artist1-album1.tar.gz
./artist1/album2/*.mp3  => ./artist1-album2.tar.gz
./artist1/album3/*.mp3  => ./artist1-album3.tar.gz
./artist2/album1/*.mp3  => ./artist2-album1.tar.gz
./artist2/album2/*.mp3  => ./artist2-album2.tar.gz
./artist3/album1/*.mp3  => ./artist3-album1.tar.gz
./artist3/album2/*.mp3  => ./artist3-album2.tar.gz
... ...
```

I'd like one-line-command or a simple script.

Comment: do you want to ZIP or do you want to TAR and GZIP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tar`:

```
for dir in */*/; do dir=${dir%/}; tar cf "${dir//\//-}.tar" "$dir"; done
```

`zip`:

```
for dir in */*/; do dir=${dir%/}; zip -0r "${dir//\//-}.zip" "$dir"; done
```

MP3 files contain already-compressed data, which cannot be compressed further - the best you would get is ~2%, and it would be many times slower - so the first example is just a `tar` archive.

If you still want Gzip compression, add a `z` option (as in `tar czf`) and replace `.tar` with `.tar.gz`. Similarly, the `-0` option to `zip` disables compression - change `-0r` to `-r` to re-enable.

---

[`${dir%/}`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#from_the_end) removes the ending `/` from `$dir`

[`${dir//\//-}`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#search_and_replace) replaces all `/` with `-`

Comment: +1 for also mentioning that mp3s are already squashed up.